# how to import ol.map.addlayer in component angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I would like to use ol.map.addlayer to add a layer from geoserver. but it comes out an error that addlayer is undefined. I know that all the function I want to use need to be imported from specific file but I cannot find where addlayer is.

How could I import addlayer?

```
  if (this.routeLayer != null){
  this.map.removeLayer(this.routeLayer)}
  else{
  this.routeLayer = new Vector({
    map: this.map,
    source: this.routeSource,

    style: new Style({
      stroke: new Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)',
        width: 8
      })
    })
  });

  // add the new layer to the map
  this.map.addlayer(this.routeLayer);

}
```

Comment: Try `addLayer` instead of `addlayer`.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. After I change this it come out another error ERROR TypeError: format.getType is not a function
    at _ol_source_Vector_.loader_ (featureloader.js:31)
    at _ol_source_Vector_.webpackJsonp.../../../../ol/source/Vector.js._ol_source_Vector_.loadFeatures (Vector.js:756)
    at _ol_renderer_canvas_VectorLayer_.webpackJsonp.../../../../ol/renderer/canvas/vectorlayer.js._ol_renderer_canvas_VectorLayer_.prepareFrame (vectorlayer.js:299)
    at _ol_renderer_canvas_Map_.webpackJsonp.../../../../ol/renderer/canvas/map.js._ol_renderer_canvas_Map_.renderFrame (map.js:161)